# Find xml element by html element id/class

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

i have a little question. How can i detect xml tag name compare with html element class? my code below:

```
   var class_main_content = $('.main_content ul').find(this.class);
   var xml_element_name = $(xml).find(class_main_content).text();
```

thx for help.

Comment: i thing both, becouse if i want to compare it notching happens...

                if ((class_main_content) == xml_element_name){
                    $('.main_content ul').remove('.main_content ul li');
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is really "How do I get the class name from an html element?" then try something like this:

```
var class_main_content = $('.main_content ul').attr("class");
```

Using `$('.main_content ul')` will return a jQuery object containing all ul elements that are descendants of elements with the class "main_content". Calling `.attr("class")` on that jQuery object will retrieve the class of the first such element.

You can then use that class name in the next statement:

```
var xml_element_name = $(xml).find(class_main_content).text();
```

If your `xml` has an element with a tag name the same as the html element's class then that xml element's text will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

thx, i'v set s.like this:

```
var class_main_content = $('.main_content ul').attr('class');
var xml_element_name = $(xml).find(class_main_content)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
if ((class_main_content) == xml_element_name){
}
```

end it's work...